# Get Dojo Radio Button Value?

Tags: javascript, html, dojo

I have an HTML form using dojo and have the following code for a radio button selection choice:

```js
dojo.require("dijit.form.RadioButton");
```

```html
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.6.2/dojo/resources/dojo.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.6.2/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.9.3/dojo/dojo.js" djConfig="parseOnLoad:true"></script>

<body class="claro">
  <input type="radio" dojoType="dijit.form.RadioButton" name="infoUrgent" value="deferrable" id="deferrable">Deferrable
  <input type="radio" dojoType="dijit.form.RadioButton" name="infoUrgent" value="immediate" id="immediate">Immediate
  <br>
```

I want to get the value for this radio button and pass it to my "backend" script, but NOT onClick or onChange, only after the user presses a Submit button I have on the form. Usually with textboxes, etc. I can get just use dijit.byId('id').value or .attr('value') but since the radio buttons both have different id's I can't use this. The docs from dojocampus mention using the name of the radio button... I'm having trouble getting this to work though... could I get some help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use dijit.form.Form instead of standard HTML form, and use myForm.attr('value').infoUrgent to get value of your radiobutton or just myForm.attr('value') to get whole form value. myForm here is dojo form object (can be found via dijit.byId etc.).

Answer (score 4):

```
require(["dojo/query"], function(djQuery){
        var retreiveSelected = function() {
        return djQuery('input[type=radio][name=infoUrgent]:checked')[0].value;
    };
})
```